# Recibo error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'precio') at script.js:"

Tags: javascript

[image]

Pongo el siguiente código y me salta error, no entiendo por qué. La idea es que en la consola me salga el total final con la suma del producto ya realizada por el código. Por ejemplo si yo elijo comprar 2 consolas arcade, me debería salir 600.000$: el problema es que el código no corre por completo y me lo termina cuando llega a la parte de .precio que seria la línea 131. El error que me salta es el siguiente:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'precio')
    at script.js:131:80
(anonymous) @ script.js:131
```

El Código:

```
let prod1 = 17.000
let prod2 = 180.000
let prod3 = 220.000
let prod4 = 17.000
let prod5 = 210.000
let prod6 = 300.000

let totalproductos = 0
let opcion

class Prueba{
    constructor (consola,control){
        this.consola = consola
        this.control = control
    }
}
let prods = [{
    prod: " Control Playstation 4 ",
    precio: 17000
    },
    {
        prod: " Playstation 4 ",
        precio: 180000
    },
    {
        prod: " Nintendo Switch ",
        precio: 220000
    },
    {
        prod: " Control Xbox One ",
        precio: 17000
    },
    {
        prod: " Xbox One ",
        precio: 210000
    },
    {
        prod: " Consola Arcade ",
        precio: 300000
    }
]
total = 0
let comprar = prompt( " ¿Que consola o control desea comprar? Ponga el nombre (Por el momento solo se puede vender un tipo de producto a la vez) \n\
1-Control playstation 4 \n\
2- Playstation 4 \n\
3-Nintendo Switch \n\
4-Control Xbox One \n\
5-Xbox One \n\
6-Consola Arcade")
if (comprar == "control playstation 4" || comprar == "playstation 4" || comprar == "nintendo switch" || comprar == "control xbox one" || comprar == "xbox one" || comprar == "consola arcade"){
    let cantidad = parseInt(prompt( ` Cúantas ${comprar} queres`))
    let subtotal = cantidad + prods.find((product) => product.prod === comprar).precio
    total = subtotal
}else{
    alert(" Elige entre las opciones que tenemos ")
}
console.log(total)
```

Comment: El error es bien obvio, no se puede leer el atributo `precio` de `undefined`. Eso es porque aquí: `prods.find((product) => product.prod === comprar)` no te está encontrando nada. Así a simple vista, lo más obvio que veo es que cuando defines `prods` todos tus productos llevan un espacio antes y después del nombre, pero en tu `if` los comparas sin espacios, así que asumo que lo estás introduciendo en el prompt sin espacios... obviamente `" Consola Arcade "` no es lo mismo que `"Consola Arcade"` así que no encuentra nada en el `find()`. Te recomiendo que quites los espacios extra al trabajar.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma más sencilla de hacerlo sería utilizando el ciclo `while`. Con el ciclo `while` hacemos que las instrucciones que están dentro se sigan repitiendo hasta que rompamos el ciclo con el `break`, y para llegar ahí, debemos cumplir la condicional `if`, ya que el `break` está dentro de la condicional.

Entonces, quiere decir que, si escribimos un número incorrecto, nos volverá a mostrar las opciones, así sucesivamente hasta que digitemos la respuesta correcta (que es del 1 al 6), ya que cuando esto ocurra, estamos cumpliendo la condicional, hacemos la operación y rompemos el ciclo con el `break`, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
let total = 0;

let prods = [
  {
    prod: ' Control Playstation 4 ',
    precio: 17000,
  },
  {
    prod: ' Playstation 4 ',
    precio: 180000,
  },
  {
    prod: ' Nintendo Switch ',
    precio: 220000,
  },
  {
    prod: ' Control Xbox One ',
    precio: 17000,
  },
  {
    prod: ' Xbox One ',
    precio: 210000,
  },
  {
    prod: ' Consola Arcade ',
    precio: 300000,
  },
];

while (true) {
    let opcion = parseInt(prompt(`
        ¿Que consola o control desea comprar? Elige un número:\n\
        1-Control Playstation 4\n\
        2-Playstation 4\n\
        3-Nintendo Switch\n\
        4-Control Xbox One\n\
        5-Xbox One\n\
        6-Consola Arcade
    `))
    
    if (opcion >= 1 && opcion <= 6) { // si digito la opción correcta, del 1 al 6...
        // hago la operación...
        let cantidad = parseInt(prompt(`Cuantas ${prods[opcion - 1].prod} deseas comprar`))
        let subtotal = cantidad * prods[opcion - 1].precio
        total += subtotal
        break; // y rompo el ciclo
    } else {
        // de lo contrario, mostramos el siguiente alert y el ciclo volverá a repetir.
        alert("Elige entre las opciones que tenemos")
    }
}

console.log(total)
```

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo. Una consulta, perdon si es medio tonta, estoy aprendiendo a programar con JS. Lo que pusiste entre [], [opcion - 1], ¿que estas diciendo ahi? Nose si se entiende la pregunta. ¿Para que pusiste el -1?

Comment: Claro, olvidé explicártelo, ahí estoy accediendo a la posición del **array**, ya que es un **array** de objetos. Entonces, ingreso a la posición con la opción que digito, imagina que pongo la opción 2, entonces ingreso a la posición 2 - 1, ¿Por qué - 1? porque las posiciones de los arrays **parten desde 0**, por eso se hace esa pequeña operación, y al ingresar a la posición, entro al valor de la clave, que en este caso la clave se llama **precio**. Esto sería una forma más fácil de acceder a los arrays de objetos, ya no necesitaría un find ni otra búsqueda más compleja.

Comment: Si tienes alguna duda, me lo haces saber. Por cierto, recuerda verificar marcándole al ✔️ si la respuesta si te sirvió, así tu pregunta estará como respondida, saludos.